# Why does PowerShell use double colon( :: ) to call static methods of a .NET class?

Tags: powershell

Is there any specific reason to use c++ style of double colon  '::' ? Why not use a simple dot like c#?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is a question for Windows PowerShell in Action.

> The :: operator is the static member accessor. Whereas the dot
>   operator retrieved instance members, the double-colon operator
>   accesses static members on a class, as is the case with the join
>   method in the example at the end of the last section. The left operand
>   to the static member accessor is required to be a type—either a type
>   literal or an expression returning a type as you see here:
>
> ```
> PS (1) > $t = [string] 
> PS (2) > $t::join('+',(1,2,3)) 
> 1+2+3 
> PS (3) >
> ```
>
> The language design team chose to use a separate operator for
>   accessing static methods because of the way static methods are
>   accessed. Here’s the problem. If you had a type MyModule with a static
>   property called Module, then the expression
>
> `[MyModule].Module`
>
> is
>   ambiguous. This is because there’s also an instance member Module on
>   the System.Type instance representing the type MyModule. Now you can’t
>   tell if the “Module” instance member on System.Type or the “Module”
>   static member on MyModule should be retrieved. By using the
>   double-colon operator, you remove this ambiguity.
>
> **Note**
>
> Other languages
>   get around this ambiguity by using the typeof() operator. Using
>   typeof() in this example, typeof(My Module).Module retrieves the
>   instance property on the Type object and MyModule.Module retrieves the
>   static property implemented by the MyModule class.

Bruce Payette (2011-08-02 16:22:31.490000-05:00). Windows PowerShell in Action, Second Edition (Kindle Locations 4494-4507). Manning Publications. Kindle Edition.

Comment: For completeness: this is different from C++ where the quad-dot operator resolves scopes/namespaces.

Comment: Is there an alternative in Powershell? E.G. `[SomeNamespace].GetType().StaticPropName`